# move files of a particular pattern to another directory

Tags: shell, wildcards, mv

In the directory `/home/in` I have files like this:

```
crust.MC12345.txt 
crust.etcMC12345.txt
crust.MC23456.txt
crust.etcMC23456.txt 
crust.etctcMC23456.txt
```

I only need to move `crust.etcMC12345.txt` and `crust.etcMC23456.txt` to another dir, `/home/out`.what is the pattern i use in the mv command for the above scenario ?

Comment: The pattern is a bit unclear. Could you edit your question to include some filenames that would match, and some that would not match?

Comment: when i use pattern crust.*MC*.txt in mv command it is moving all 4 files where as i only need crust.etcMC12345.txt and crust.etcMC23456.txt

Comment: Then why not do `mv crust.etc* dest/`?

Comment: i tried and it worked . thanks a lot. but what if u dont know how many literals are there before MC like etctMC123.txt and etctcMC125.txt

Comment: I tried to update your Q, can you please take a few moments and help everyone help you? It's not clear what files you have, and what files you want to move.

Comment: Can I `mv crust*.txt subdir` or does `subdir` have to be `mv crust*.txt ./subdir`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question the answer is very simple:

```
mv crust.etcMC* /home/out
```

or if `etc` is not literal string, but for example any three characters then:

```
mv crust.???MC* /home/out
```

Comment: i also have other files with names like crust.tecMC12345.txt crust.etcMC1232.txt and so on

Comment: Please see the edit of my answer and specify precisely what files do you have.

Comment: crust.etcMC123.txt,crust.tecMC234.txt,crust.cetMC345.txt,crust.MC123.txt are some sample files in my dir how do i only mv files with names crust.tecMCxxx.txt so crust.xxMCxxx.txt x is variable

Comment: This is incompatible with your question above: `i need files with names crust.etcMC.xyz`. And now you are saying `do i only mv files with names crust.tecMCxxx.txt`. So do you want to move only `crust.etcMC*` or `crust.tecMC*` or both, or neither? Please don't hurry with the answer, take your time, edit the question taking care of proper formatting and explain precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move files which have *at least* one character between `crust.` and `MC` you can use

```
mv crust.?*MC /home/out
```

Here `?` stands for one literal and `*` for zero or more, and hence the combination `?*` stands for one or more characters. It will therefore skip files like `crust.MC12345.txt`.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, since it looks to me that this is the correct answer to the question which is enlightened in the second comment of the OP after the question.